# Autoincrement filename in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-drive-shared-drive

How I can add function to Docs for all my accounts, when I open new doc's file it want find my folder where I now + last filename and increment 1 & save.

For default Google Doc save document  with name 'Untitled document', but I want that it save it:

folder_1.1001.doc
folder_1.1002.doc

and if I create file in next Folder2:

folder_2.001.doc
folder_2.002.doc.

My bad code:

```
// Show current folder name & root folder name
function makeFilename() {

  // Get current folder name
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  thisFileId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();

  var thisFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(thisFileId);
  var parentFolder = thisFile.getParents();
  var currentFolderName = parentFolder.next();
  ui.alert(currentFolderName);

  // get all files in currentFolderName
  var files = parentFolder;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();  
   //  Logger.log(file.getName());
   DocumentApp.getUi().alert(file.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: [Edit] to Post your current code and what you've done so far. [mcve]

Comment: I add some code what I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample code:

```
// Show current folder name 
function makeFilename() {

  // Get current file name
  const ui = DocumentApp.getUi(),
    doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(), //Added
    thisFileId = doc.getId(),
    thisFileName = doc.getName();

  const thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(thisFileId);//Modified from getFolderById
  const parentFolder = thisFile.getParents();
  const currentFolder = parentFolder.next();//Modified from currentFolderName
  const currentFolderName = currentFolder.getName();//Added
  //ui.alert(currentFolderName);

  /*Store a init file in root to getLatestFileNumber*/
  var initIter = DriveApp.getFilesByName(currentFolderName + 'init000'),
    initBool = initIter.hasNext(),
    init;
  if (!initBool) {
    init = DriveApp.createFile(currentFolderName + 'init000', '0');
  } else {
    init = initIter.next();
  }

  /*Get current Number and format it to 4 digits*/
  var currentNum = init.getBlob().getDataAsString() * 1 + 1,
    formatNum = ('00000' + currentNum).substr(-4);

  /*If filename already contains folderName, do nothing*/
  if (!(thisFileName.search(currentFolderName) + 1)) {
    doc.setName(currentFolderName + formatNum).saveAndClose();
    init.setContent(currentNum);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)
- [Document#setName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#setName(String))
- [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob)

Comment: I have a few questions - I do not really understand some lines of code:
 
   var initIter = DriveApp.getFilesByName (currentFolderName + 'init000')

I so understand that a line (currentFolderName + 'init000') should plus to a directory name a phrase init000? The result should be of the type: Folder002init000?

and 
var currentNum = init.getBlob().getDataAsString() * 1 + 1,

why we use getDataAsString() * 1 + 1 ? what is that mean this construction?

If my real folder names MT.100-100\MT.100-100.1001.doc how I can modified code?

Comment: @Olek We need a place to store the latest filenumber. In this case, we create a file named 'Folderinit000' in the root of your drive. You can take a look at it. Then whenever the script is run, we search for this file and take the string , multiply by 1 to get a integer, add a 1 for the next file....

Comment: I don't understand why we need create new file in root directory :(
Ok - maybe I make a new folder ( _tmp) where all files are saves. or find another way.. 
I little bit modificate code, adding +'.' to this code
` doc.setName(currentFolderName +'.' + formatNum)`
Tel me - how it possible run this script for all users in my domain where anybody create a new file, not file from template? Idk how I can run this script for default for all users. if it possible?

Comment: @Olek You need to find a common resource a drive/file(a public file) which all of you in your domain can access... Then get that file by its `ID`. Note that the above is just a sample proof of concept... You need to adapt it to your environment....

Comment: Given this script, how would you apply this script to all google docs that will be created on the fly ?

Comment: @str028 Kindly ask a new question.

Comment: @TheMaster here is the ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825332/how-to-apply-google-appscript-to-all-google-docs :)