# current folder name in google script, google drive? How?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Is it possible to get a current folder name when I make a new Doc file? My script shows for me all the folders recursively from the root, but not the current one:

In a [Google Drive Api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String)) I can't find info about current folder :( Please help me.

```
// Log the name of every folder in the user's Drive.
var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
while (folders.hasNext()) {
var folder = folders.next();
//Logger.log(folder.getName());
DocumentApp.getUi().alert(folder.getName());
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, how are you selecting the current folder? When you create a new file using the scripts it's placed in the root of the drive unless you specify the destination folder. Your not using a recursive function here but a loop to iterate through all folders in your drive.

Comment: oh sorry - I can't create a new file using script, only via Button and mouse. One answer that below already helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Try:

```
var id = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();//get id of the current document
DocumentApp.getUi().alert(DriveApp.getFileById(id) //getFile
  .getParents() //getParentFolders
  .next() //getFirstParentFolder
  .getName());//getNameOfThatFolder
```

Comment: Thank you |'-'| 
My code, what I find yesterday little bit different and not clean:
 `
 // Get current folder name
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  thisFileId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();

  var thisFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(thisFileId);
  var parentFolder = thisFile.getParents();
  var currentFolderName = parentFolder.next();
  ui.alert(currentFolderName);
`

Can you help me  [with this questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050887/autoincrement-filename-in-google-docs)

Comment: @Olek `var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(thisFileId);` NOT `getFolderById()`