# How can I apply Google Apps Script to all Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Below solution is intended to generate auto-increment ID as replacement to default name "Untitiled document" of Google Docs.

[Autoincrement filename in Google Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050887/autoincrement-filename-in-google-docs)

The solution was clear to me. However, I'm thinking an option on how to apply this script to all google docs that will be created on the fly? Maybe add-ons?

Comment: About `all google docs that will be created on the fly`, in this case, is the manually created Document without using a script included?

Comment: @Tanaike yes, if its possible to apply the script to all googledocs within the drive ?

Comment: currently i can only see the script working on one google docs that has bound scrpit. i want to apply as well the script to the other docs that will be newly created.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about checking whether new Document is created using the script running with [the time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)? In this case, a Google Apps script is required to be prepared. And, the checking cycle is decided by the time of the time-driven trigger. It's not the real time. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Auto-renaming documents can't be done on-the-fly, that is to say, there is no way of making a script run automatically on document creation. You can however check for new documents in the Drive and rename them using a script which is on a repeating timer.*

#### More Information:

As far as simple triggers go, according to the documentation:

> The script must be bound to a Google Sheets, Slides, Docs, or Forms file, or else be an add-on that extends one of those applications.

So this is a no-go. Installable triggers however can be run as a standalone project, and can be run on a time-based trigger. The shortest time frame for the recurring interval an installable trigger can be set to is ***once a minute***. I hope this is suitable for your needs.

What you can therefore do, is check your Drive for Documents that have been created in the latest interval, and then rename them based on your increment value.

#### Code:

Modifying the wonderful code provided by TheMaster in the question you linked:

```js
function renameFiles() {  
  // change this to be your file name prefix
  const fileNameStarter = "init";  
  var dict = {};  
  var now = new Date();
  var newDate = new Date(now.getTime() - 60000);
  // The date search has to be in UTC so we modify the time to be in the 
  // correct format
  var searchString = Utilities.formatDate(newDate, "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

  // Get a list of newly modified Drive files 
  var newFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles('modifiedDate > "' + searchString + '"');
  var arr = [];
  
  while (newFiles.hasNext()) {
    var currFile = newFiles.next();
  
    // check if the file is a) a Google Doc and b) already named correctly  
    if (currFile.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS && !currFile.getName().startsWith(fileNameStarter)) {
      dict[new Date(currFile.getDateCreated())] = currFile.getId();
      arr.push(new Date(currFile.getDateCreated()));
    }
  }
  // sorts the files not named correctly by date
  arr.sort()
  
  const correctlyNamedFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains '" + fileNameStarter + "' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'");
  var count = 0;
  // gets the number of already named files so to get the new number
  while (correctlyNamedFiles.hasNext()) {
    count++;
    correctlyNamedFiles.next()
  }  
  
  // get the new files to rename, and rename them
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    count++
    var formatNum = ('00000' + count).substr(-4);
    DriveApp.getFileById(dict[arr[j]]).setName(fileNameStarter + formatNum)
  }
}
```

Remember that the [`modifiedDate` file query term](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms#file_properties) defaults to UTC if the timezone offset isn't specified.

#### Creating an Installable Trigger:

Save the script with the save icon, press the run button (►), and confirm the authentication of running the script.

From here, following the Edit > Current project's triggers menu item, you will have a new page open in the G Suite Developer Hub. Click the + Add Trigger button in the bottom right and set up the trigger settings as follows:

- Choose which function to run: `renameFiles`
- Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
- Select event source: `Time-driven`
- Select type of time based trigger: `Minutes timer`
- Select minute interval: `Every minute`

And press save. This will now run once a minute, renaming all newly modified Document files with the `initXXXX` format, unless the file is already correctly named. You can change the prefix to what you like by editing the `fileNameStarter` variable.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Search query terms | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms)
- [G Suite and Drive MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)
- [Method `formatDate(date, timeZone, format` | Class Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

#### Related Questions:

- [Autoincrement filename in Google Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52224961/11551468)